# How do i fight my landlord for leaking & flooding from dishwasher & dishdisposal?

Tags: mold, water-damage

My dishwasher  and disposal never worked. I moved in Aug 2018 and it leaked & flooded my kitchen for over 2 years before my landlord removed disposal.
My kids room was on opposite side of wall which stayed smelling of musty foul smell. Their room stayed moist especially their mattresses.
The dishwasher would literally flood my floor as well as under the sink. The smell was so bad. The only reason they pulled out the disposal was because my daughter has a life threatening chronic lung disease and her doctor was concerned about her living situation at home that's causing her more respiratory problems.
So I called the maintenance man again and told him what the doctor said and had plumber come take it out, but never replaced wood or cabinets under the sink. Did nothing but give me a black rubber mat to put over the rotted black wood.
I had to strip their room and throw everything away and still they couldn't sleep in that room. The moisture was so bad, as well as the smell.
I got evicted in July 2021 for non payment because I was so tired of nobody not doing anything about it. How do I start to prove my case? Been homeless ever since due to eviction

Comment: Local health department probably the best in mold cases.  Building department/inspection for rotting wood.  Might not help you, but should make life nasty for landlord.  A landlord/tenet lawyer(some places have free/low cost solutions for tenets).

Comment: I hope you took pictures or have written communication documenting your complaints. If they fixed the issue after your eviction then good luck proving there was ever an issue. I'm sorry for your situation but it's been 1 year and 4 months since you moved out. If there is a new tenant then you *can* try approaching them and ask if the issue still exists and that you wish to mutually help each other.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems better suited on https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although it seems like you almost certainly had valid cause for complaint, you went about it in completely the wrong way by not paying rent - and the fact that a judge granted an eviction confirms that.

Comment: Are you in a rent control area?  You need to talk to a legal aid society about getting the eviction expunged from your record. Other than that you'll need to seriously investigate #VanLife.  Or in the UK or certain other places, boat life. Then it's your home and you resolve problems like that by using your own skills and money to fix it.

Comment: i wouldn't hold out too much hope of recovering money of satisfaction from that landlord; it's just not worth the expense, time, and hassle; you've got bigger fish to fry.

Answer (score 3):

This question is not technically about home improvement, however it deserves an answer.
You lived in a situation that was unhealthy. When the landlord was not willing to correct the problems in a reasonable time, your recourse should have been to notify the health department for your location. This is good info for any person living in a situation where the landlord will not enact repairs need to keep living quarters healthy. There are consequences. The Health Department may declare the unit unfit to live in and you may have to move. However now you have a complaint that is verified and registered and you do not have an eviction on your rental record. You may also seek and be qualified for rental assistance ( even now)  Check with your local Department of Housing.
To be qualified for rental assistance units have to pass governmental inspections. Therefore you have some assurance that the unit is safe and an advocate in your corner if there are future issues.
This may all be confusing, but there is help out there. If you do not know where to go, ask for guidance at the Salvation Army, The Red cross, A YMCA, a church or even a fire station or police department just as you did here. Often there are programs to help people such as yourself...they are sometimes difficult to find.  Good Luck